# How can you resolve a "resource already exists" error in Cloudformation without deleting the stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

During a deploy I got:

```
 ❌  geoms (geoms-justincollum) failed: Error: The stack named geoms-justincollum 
failed to deploy: UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: Resource handler returned message: 
"Resource of type 'AWS::Glue::Schema' with identifier 'justincollum_geography.geoms.canonical' 
already exists." (RequestToken: 056ac70c-597a-2ce7-8748-877dd8bc29e2, HandlerErrorCode: AlreadyExists)
    at FullCloudFormationDeployment.monitorDeployment 
(/Users/justin.collum/Documents/work/geoms/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:426:10236)
```

Since it's trying to create something that already exists I deleted the resource. Then I deployed again and it went fine. Then I rebased and changed some code. The next time I tried to deploy:

```
❌  geoms (geoms-justincollum) failed: Error: The stack named geoms-justincollum failed to deploy:
UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: Resource handler returned message: "Resource of type 'AWS::Glue::Schema'
with identifier
'SchemaId(SchemaArn=arn:aws:glue:us-east-2:988990816172:schema/geoms-justincollum/justincollum_geography.geoms.canonical)' was not found." (RequestToken: 7758a737-e1d5-3bce-a8bf-c7cc3d194b1e,
HandlerErrorCode: NotFound)
    at FullCloudFormationDeployment.monitorDeployment
    (/Users/justin.collum/Documents/work/geomsp/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:426:10236)
```

(note: some of those names have been changed to protect IP)

So it existed and now it can't deploy because it can't find it I guess.

When I encounter an error like `HandlerErrorCode: AlreadyExists` is there a simplish way to get that resource into my stack? That seems like the most straightforward solution here.

Comment: Did you try to import the resource? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-existing-stack.html

Comment: Is your intent to deploy a new Glue Schema, defined in your CloudFormation template?  Or is the schema a pre-existing resource created outside CloudFormation?